# Populating dropdown form select according to number of checked Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How can I populate a `select` option according to the number of checked checkboxes?

I have 5 `checkboxes` in my HTML page. If I check 3 checkboxes then the `select` should show options as `1,2,3`. Similarly, if I have 5 checkboxes selected then from `select` options should show a list of values `1,2,3,4,5`.

I am trying below code

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><form:checkbox class="source" path="c1" value="${archbean.c1}" />Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><form:checkbox class="source" path="c2" value="${archbean.c2}" />Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><form:checkbox class="source" path="c3" value="${archbean.c3}" />Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><form:checkbox class="source" path="c4" value="${archbean.c4}" />Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><form:checkbox class="source" path="c5" value="${archbean.c5}" />Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var selected_value = [];
$('.source').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        selected_value.push($(this).val());
        console.log(selected_value);
    } else {
        //error
    }
});
```

I am getting the list of boolean values but how to use them in `select` is a doubt here.

Comment: **How to populate form select option according to checked checkboxes**. By coding

Comment: What have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: on every change of checkbox populate the select box with selected checkboxes

Comment: @MayankPandeyz sorry for that ...i was just trying out the code so could not add it. No made the edit

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
      if(this.checked){
         //add to select list
      }
      else{
        //remove item from select list
      }
   });
});
```